# How to get the plugged/unplugged cable state

Tags: winapi, networking

I know about the IsNetworkAlive function from the Windows API but IsNetworkAlive returns false until there's any network activity.

That is, if you start your computer and test connectivity it will return false. If you then ping another computer (or recieve a ping or any network activity from another computer) then it will start returning true.

Is there any alternative or does anyone know a workaround for this?

Things I've tried so far:

- Ping to the local host (no go as there isn't really any network activity)
- Ping to the local address (the same as before)

**Note:** I know there's another question very similar to this one, but my problem here is with IsNetworkAlive behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want: [Check network connection status using C#.net](http://riteshk.blogspot.com/2007/02/check-network-connection-status-using.html)?

(It use [InternetGetConnectedState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384702(VS.85).aspx) WinInet function)

Answer (score 1):

The WinInet functions should meet your needs. Of particular interest is the `InternetGetConnectedState` function.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using

- [NetworkChange Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.aspx)
- [The Connection Monitor Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc540740.aspx)

Comment: Nice, but I'm using winapi, not .NET ... I don't have access to .NET